# I can't jump to the line on my texmaker

Tags: texmaker, forward-inverse-search

I'm sure a lot of people is having the same problem as mine because I've tried to make this work in two completely different computers and nothing happens.

I'm trying to use "Jump to the line" on my texmaker and it's not working. I'm trying on my notebook running Linux and on my PC desktop Running Windows. I will leave the information of my two operational systems here (maybe one is easier to fix than another).

---

> **Notebook:**
>
> Linux Mint 17 KDE 64-bit version of Texmaker: 4.1-1 (I downloaded it
>   from software manager)

---

> **PC desktop**
>
> Windows 8 PRO (64 bit)
>
> Version of Texmaker 4.4.1 (I suppose it's the latest because I
>   downloaded it from the official site some weeks ago)

---

If someone could help me I would be very grateful not only because of me, but because this would help a lot of people having the same problem which goes here using search engines.

If you need ANY information of my PC, my Texmaker or my operational system, just ask and I will answer very quickly.